# Error: $ is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am working with a accordion which have gray scale images on load and on mouse over it images show in its real color.
Where is conflicting J query in my script..
Getting `error : $ is not a function`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kwicks.js"></script>
<script src="js/greyScale.js"></script>
<script>
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function () {
  $j('.greyScale').hide().fadeIn(1000); // fade in the grayscaled images to avoid visual jump
});
$j(window).load(function () {
  // user window.load to ensure images have been loaded
  $('.greyScale').greyScale({
    fadeTime: 500
    // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {
  $('.kwicks').kwicks({
    max: 535,
    spacing: 10,
    sticky: false
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: change all $ with $j, as you have used $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Yograj Sir. Gr8... i solved.. whoooppp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick all of your script code in a closure like this:

```
(function($) {

...

}(jQuery));
```

Then you can just use `$` instead of `$j` and there will be no conflict.

Comment: @NareshSatd Great. Some advice since you're new to SO. You'll need to tick someone's solution (not necessarily mine) and click on the up arrow for any solutions you felt were beneficial. People can get cross if you don't - not me, mind you ;)

Comment: i tried with all of your solution and with all i solved my problem.. so i gave thanks to all.. :-)

Comment: @NareshSatd  You need to TICK someone's solution, though :)

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.noConflict();` means that jQuery doesn't use `$` anymore but `$j` so that `$` is freed for other use. If you don't define `$` anywhere else, it will remain undefined.

If you have `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` it means you have to use `$j` (or `jQuery`) from then on, or do something like:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $().ready(function() {
        $('.kwicks').kwicks({
            ...
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

On the other hand, if `$` is available, why use `noConflict()` at all?

Answer (score 0):

After using .noConflict(), you won't be able to access the jQuery Object with $, so you should change all your jQuery calls.